# creating child process of a child process in unix

Tags: shell, unix, process, fork

I need to create three processes as x,y and z. Then the process x should create two child processes like x1 and x2 while x is their parent.....
I know that using fork we can create a copy of the current process, but my question is how to create a child process of a child process?

Comment: another fork in the child.  Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you have to call fork from child process. But, make sure you don't create fork bomb.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb